# Why are JavaScript sort comparator arguments are in opposite order?

Tags: javascript, sorting

Seems very basic but I can't find any info on why is it happening.

I'm using the canonical [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort an array of objects and it seems the order in which the elements are passed into the compare callback is the opposite order. e.g.

```js
let items = [
  { name: 'Edward', value: 21 },
  { name: 'Sharpe', value: 37 },
  { name: 'And', value: 45 },
  { name: 'The', value: -12 },
  { name: 'Magnetic', value: 13 },
  { name: 'Zeros', value: 37 }
];

// sort by value
items.sort(function (a, b) {
  console.log(a.name, b.name);
  return -1; // should keep the original order
});

// getting
// Sharpe Edward
// And Sharpe
// The And
// Magnetic The
// Zeros Magnetic
```

Again documentation says:

> If compareFunction(a, b) returns less than 0, leave a and b unchanged.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm getting `Edward Sharpe, 
Sharpe And, 
And The, 
The Magnetic, 
Magnetic Zeros`. What browser are you using?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Interesting, I'm using latest Brave (Blink, Chromium 90)

Comment: Your understanding of the documentation is incorrect. The sort comparator function must return consistent results for the two passed-in values, regardless of the order in which they're passed. In other words, sometimes `a` will be some value and `b` another, but the comparator may be called again with the values swapped. The return value must be consistent. Also, -1 does not mean "leave values in current order", is is an explicit indication that the first value (`a`) should go before the second (`b`).

Comment: for keeping the original order, you need to return zero.

Comment: I'm highly dubious of the accuracy of that MDN article; the `-1` thing does not make sense because there's no way the sort algorithm keeps track of *original* ordering, or at least I would find that extremely surprising.

Comment: That phrasing is pretty confusing tbh

Comment: @adiga well the ES2022 spec does have some weird stuff in it that's (typically) extremely dense and hard to understand. This seems like a question for TJ :)

Comment: @Pointy I checked the history of the MDN page, it was changed 3 months ago: https://github.com/mdn/content/commit/605989096dbd1e122e2952a8726129a00aa04856 . The earlier version was *"If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns less than 0, sort `a` to an index lower than `b`*" That is much more clearer and consistent with the *greater than 0* part.

Comment: OK I understand the weird part of the spec; it basically says the sorting process has to work properly :)

Comment: Here's the link to the issue: https://github.com/mdn/content/issues/2198

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [specification](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-sortcompare) says:

> If comparefn is not undefined and is not a consistent comparison
> function for the elements of this array (see below), the sort order is
> implementation-defined.

That's precisely your case. Your function is not consistent as it always returns -1 without actually comparing the two elements, so you shouldn't expect the result to be consistent (and you might find differences between browsers).

Comment: Thanks @Guerric. "Your function is not consistent as it always returns -1". Can you define "consistent" in this context? Always returning -1 seems pretty consistent to me :)

Comment: @krulik -1 means "a should go before b".  The function has to be transitively consistent, so if a should go before b, and b should go before c, then a should also go before c.  If the elements of the array are passed in a different order (like, b before a) then it fails that requirement.

Comment: So consistent in this context means returning the same value regardless of the order in which (a, b) are passed. Seems obvious now, but it's not obvious at all from the documentation. Intuitively I thought the array is iterated in order.

Comment: It is iterated in order that's precisely the reason why it outputs as reversed because each item must go before the previous one (at least in V8 engine)

Comment: @krulik well the actual algorithm used is *not* in the spec. If you think about how some sorting algorithms work, while it's in process the array will be "halfway" sorted, and there may have been some element interchanges (almost certainly). Once the array has started to be re-ordered, two elements that have already been compared may need to be compared again, but they may be in relatively different places in the partially-sorted array.

Comment: @GuerricP the output in the question is during the sorting process, not of the result. At least in my browser's implementation the (a, b) arguments are passed as what I'd call as (b, a) in each iteration

Comment: @Pointy the missing part for me was not the specific algorithm but the point about the order of the arguments / returning the same value regardless of order.

Comment: Your 2 first inputs are `Edward` and `Sharpe`, which are passed to the compare function as `Sharpe`,  `Edward` (implementation defined) and your function says that `Sharpe` should go before `Edward` that's why it reverses

Comment: "implementation defined" were exactly the missing words for me (also the reasoning behind them)

Comment: But why is `a` / `b` switched to `b` / `a`? You all are correct that the OPs implementation is incorrect, but the question was why are the arguments switched?

Comment: @GN. the point is that the JavaScript engine can call `comparefn` as many times as he wants and with the parameters in any order, until the sort is fully solved. Its internal algorithm is an implementation detail.